# Add Gmail to Send To Mail Recipient Right Click in Win10

Tags: windows-10, email, gmail

I have Chrome set up as my default Browser and Gmail set up as my mail handler. Mailto links open in Gmail.

I wanted the ability to be in Windows File Explorer, right click on a file and then send to a mail recipient via Gmail.

Is there any way to set this up? Seems to work with Thunderbird etc. but I cannot seem to set it up to use Gmail.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is a program called "MAPI for Gmail" which adds the Simple MAPI DLL for GMail. But I haven't tried this program though. This is the only option that I can think of.

Comment: @w32sh Thanks! That did look promising. But looks like they are no longer functional. I could not manage to download that product.

Answer (score 0):

The reason Thunderbird, Microsoft Outlook, and so on works is because they are installed software in your device. This way, Windows recognizes them as tool to send mail and enables the `Send to` menu.

Currently Gmail, on the other hand, is not a software you install in your Windows. It runs from inside a browser in this S.O.. Therefore, you can't right click on a file and send to Gmail, as Windows isn't aware you are running something that could receive files in your browser. The drag and drop files to new mail messages works pretty well on Gmail to replace that, though.